# query string on asp net with HasKeys

Tags: c#, asp.net

i can't run a query string with hash keys.

I have try :

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest q = Request;
        NameValueCollection n = q.QueryString;
        if (n.HasKeys())
        {
            string k = n.GetKey(0);
            if (k == "one")
            {
                string v = n.Get(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work

Can some one help me ? Or give me another way ?

Comment: Why not just use var v = Request["one"]?

Comment: Let me try, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

`public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest q = Request;
        NameValueCollection n = q.QueryString;
        if (n.HasKeys())
        {
            string k = n.GetKey(0);
            if (k == "one")
            {
                string v = n.Get(0);
            }
            if (k == "two")
            {
                string v = n.Get(0);
            }
        }
    }
}`

Alternative way :

`public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpRequest q = Request;
        string v = q.QueryString["one"];
        if (v != null)
        {
        }
        v = q.QueryString["two"];
        if (v != null)
        {
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks , you are so helpful